# Laravel FormRequest: client sends attribute with dots inside

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Client sends something like this:

```
foo.1.bar=hello
```

in my FormRequest class I have tried:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'foo.1.bar' => 'string|nullable' // does not work

            'foo' => 'array|nullable' // does not work

            'foo' => [ // does not work
              '1' => [
                'bar' => 'string|nullable'
              ]
            ]
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: hm, how would you do that?

Comment: @mwager tried this `'foo.*.bar' => 'string|nullable'`

Comment: Please can you show how you're sending the data i.e. is it a straightforward form or are you using javascript?

Comment: When the validation *should* fail what the output for `dd($this->all())` ?

Comment: $request->all() returns: array:36 [
  "foo.1.bar" => "hello" ... but $request->validated() does not contain "foo.1.bar" anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value of the parameter manually and then validating it:

```
class YourRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [...];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $value = $this->get('foo.1.bar') ?: $this->get('foo_1_bar');

        $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) use ($value) {
            if ($value == null) {
                $validator->errors()->add('foo.1.bar', 'Error Message.');
                $validator->errors()->add('foo_1_bar', 'Error Message.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Laravel replace the dots in key with underscore?

Comment: $value is "hello" - but in my controller $request->validated() still does not contain key "foo.1.bar" with value "hello" - did I miss something?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier it does for `$request->get()` on the 5.8.36 version that I tried.

Comment: Does Laravel replace the dots in key with underscore? does not seem to happen: $request->all() returns: array:36 [ "foo.1.bar" => "hello"

Comment: @mwager for `$request->get()` I was able to validate this with underscores, but it looks like it works differently in the `rules()` array.